# Unable to Host a WCF service using IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I am using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx) guide to host my simple WCF service in IIS. but I am getting this error when I try to test it in Internet Explorer:
[image: Here is the error image]

I have created a folder called "IISHostedWCFService" under the Default Web Site in IIS Manager and inside it I added an Application called "IISHostedService". I have also created a Service.svc file with this code:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="CalculatorService" %>
```

an App.config file with this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the default configuration
        model introduced in .NET Framework 4 -->
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService">

        <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host:                                        http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />

        <!-- The mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I also created a folder called App_Code and inside that I created Service.cs which includes my source code:

```
 using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

    namespace CalculatorService
    {
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface ICalculator
        {
            [OperationContract]
            double add(double n1, double n2);
            [OperationContract]
            double multiply(double n1, double n2);
        }

        public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
        {
            public double add(double n1, double n2)
            {
                return n1 + n2;
            }

            public double multiply(double n1, double n2)
            {
                return n1 * n2;
            }
        }
    }
```

I think it might be a namespace issue as I'm not sure exactly what my namespace should be, I'm confused.

I am a beginner in WCF and I appreciate any comments or suggestions for hosting WCF using IIS.
Thank you

**UPDATE1:**
Thanks to Ric .Net's answer I have a better understanding of namesapces but I'm still getting the Server Error.
I updated my Service.svc and App.config file as Ric.Net suggested, I also set the

```
<service name="CalculatorService.CalculatorService">
```

Here is the new Error:
[image: New Error]

Comment: Because `PrintScreen` is too mainstream?

Comment: lol I was working for 5 hours straight I guess my brain was Throwing Exceptions :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of testing I finally figured it out:
The guides I was using to get the WCF up and running in IIS were not accurate, there was something missing and it was the .dll file. I simply created a folder called **"bin"** and I copied my **WCF service .dll** file in it, and it worked perfectly. 
Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your on the right way. It is, as far I can see from what you posted, a namespace issue.

ISS/WCF needs the full name of the class or interface that has the `ServiceContract` attribute on it. It also needs the full name of the implementation that is implementing the `ServiceContract`.

Looking at the supplied code this would be:
`CalculatorService.ICalculator` and for the implementation `CalculatorService.CalculatorService`

You svc file would become:

ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="CalculatorService.CalculatorService"

and the config:

```
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="CalculatorService.ICalculator" />
```

But I can't be 100% sure because you can make global changes in the project settings. You can check in Visual Studio by opening the 'class view' window. This will show you a tree view of your projects in your solution. Locate the project where `ICalculator` is defined and  by expanding you step from the root namespace to the interface/class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I made those changes and I still get the Server Error page, this time with the type CalculatorService.CalculatorService. I also checked the Class View in Visual Studio and I believe that the namespaces you suggested are correct, but I still see the Error page.

Comment: Did you reset the AppPool associated with your site?

Comment: Also delete the mexBinding for now, you're not using it now, so let's keep things simple.

Comment: About reseting AppPool I'm not sure how and why to reset it

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps to solve it:

1) in service markup, change the Service to CalculatorService.CalculatorService

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="CalculatorService" %>
```

2) in your config file, change the name attribute of service tag to CalculatorService.CalculatorService like this:

```
<service name="CalculatorService.CalculatorService">
```

3) again in config file change contract attribute of endpoint to your interface right path, like this:

```
<endpoint address=""
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          contract="CalculatorService.ICalculator" />
```